# How long to brute force 16 character secret key

Tags: bash, performance, security, authentication, encryption

I have generated a 16 character alphanumeric secret key in bash with this command:

```
key=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 16 | head -n 1)
```

I am thinking of using this key to encrypt a password.

How long would it generally take for an attacker to brute force to find a key that would decrypt a password encrypted using this method?

Comment: well, what's your encryption algorithm? rot13? It'd be O(1). aes256 O(infinity)

Comment: If you're asking whether it is cryptographically secure, then [the answer is yes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key).

Comment: I am using the OpenSSL EVP library in C, found here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit.html. Also, @Assaf Lavie, can you comment on the brute force method?

Comment: @Marc B, yes I plan to use aes 256, so it would be a 32 character (32 byte or 256 bit) secret key. So it would take almost infinite time?

Comment: well, not infinite, but barring a fundamental breakthrough in mathematics or someone finding a flaw in the algorithm, aes256 is effectively unbreakable.

Comment: @Marc B, but what if they get lucky and brute force it in a reasonable time? Like a couple hours? What if they are that lucky? Is that a possibility?

Comment: if they beat 1:gazillions odds and get it first try, they should probably run out to buy a lottery ticket, because they're about to have a meteor fall on their heads while simultaneously accidentally setting off the world's nuclear stockpile the next time they like something on farcebook.

Comment: @Marc B lol ok I see.

Comment: @Marc B And what about 128 bit AES? How secure is that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "unclear what you are asking" because there are too many unknowns. Secure enough to protect your what, against what?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 62 possibilities for each character, and 16 characters.  This translates to 62^16 (47672401706823533450263330816) trials worse case, or half of that on average.  If the attacker can do a billion trials per second, that means 47672401706823533450 seconds, which is about 1511681941489 years.  I think that's pretty good protection.  You could even chop off a few characters and still feel pretty safe.

Note, I would not be saying the same thing if you had chosen a 16 character password from your brain (rather than using /dev/urandom): human brains are not good at choosing good cryptographic keys.